# Copy Rows to another table but with a condition

Tags: mysql

I trying to copy all data from old table to new table 
basically i want to copy all rows that sum of amount by side column which is greater than other side , and keep the side that is equals 3

so this is old table

```
id | board_id | fight_id | user_id | side | amount | events
1 |     2           |   1            |  1           |  2    | 500    | 1
2 |     1           |   1            |  1           |  1    | 220    | 1
3 |     2           |   1            |  1           |  2    | 500    | 1
4 |     1           |   1            |  1           |  1    | 100    | 1
5 |     3           |   1            |  1           |  3    | 270    | 1
```

this is my new table i want

```
id| board_id   | fight_id   | user_id  | side  |amount  | events
1 |     2           |   1            |  1           |  2    | 500    | 1
2 |     2           |   1            |  1           |  2    | 500    | 1
3 |     3           |   1            |  1           |  3    | 270    | 1
```

i tried this code

```
  INSERT INTO new_points(board_id,fight_id,user_id,side,amount,events) SELECT board_id,fight_id,user_id,side,amount,events, IF(side = 1,SUM(amount),0) AS s1, IF(side = 2,SUM(amount),0) AS s2,IF(side = 3,SUM(amount),0) AS s3 FROM points WHERE s1 < s2 OR s2 < s1 AND s3 != 0))
```

but not working

Edit :
Now its working

```
INSERT INTO new_points(board_id,fight_id,user_id,side,amount,events) SELECT board_id,fight_id,user_id,side,amount,events FROM (SELECT board_id,fight_id,user_id,side,amount,events, IF(side = 1,SUM(amount),0) AS s1, IF(side = 2,SUM(amount),0) AS s2,IF(side = 3,SUM(amount),0) AS s3 FROM points)a WHERE a.side = (CASE WHEN a.s1 < a.s2 WHEN 2 ELSE 1 END)
```

but the problem is that im not getting exact rows
instead im getting the less than value i getting the 
2 , 3 rows  not the 1, 3  rows base in old table and also if side is equals to 3 i want to copy it

Edit 2 : fixed

Thank you

Comment: show the SQL error or explain what 'not working' is by a verbose comparison of actual and expected result

Comment: I don't see how you can distinguish side/other side.Especially since your sample data the first 4 rows are 2 repeated pairs.(ignoring amount) And please don't edit to make less clear.

Comment: `keep the side that is equals 3` what does it mean?

Comment: if side is equals 3 then copy the rows contains side 3

Comment: But not responded to the comments...